# Java asynchronous method call using executor service

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice

I have method which does an api call,

```
public Response getPinNumber(int userId){
 // I call a method to get the pin (method 1)
 // Here i have to call another method asynchronously which should 
  not wait for method1 to complete. 
}
```

How can i do this in java? Should i use executorservice or threading?

Comment: Executor service is better.

Comment: @Weibo Li can u give one sample how this can be done using executor service?

Comment: Executor service reduces the number of lines. Thread will increase LOC.

Comment: @Shriram any sample??

Comment: r u asking any sample for executor service ?

Comment: @Shriram ya sample with executorservice

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html  http://www.journaldev.com/1069/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use threads.
You need to create class that implements Runnable interface, then in its overriden method you place content to execute.

```
   class SomeClass implements Runnable{
       @Overriden
       void run(){
       //contents to execute here
       }
    }
```

Then in your method you create new Thread as follows:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new SomeClass());
```

then run it:

```
thread1.run();
```

After executing run() method returns immediately.
You can create as many thread as you want following this example.